# How many solutions does the equation have?

Tags: functions, polynomials

(a) Sketch the graph of y=(x−p)^2 × (x−q) where p < q.

(b) How many solutions does the equation (x−p)^2 × (x−q)=k have when k > 0?

I have understood part(a) of the question and have got it correct. But I do not understand part(b) correctly. I thought the answer would be zero but the answer is one.

Can you explain what part(b) is asking for exactly and why the answer is one?

Thanks:)

[image]

Comment: Try to think of $b$ as trying to find how many times the graph of the function intersects the horizontal line $y = k$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please, refer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to properly ask question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The roots of the equation $$y=f(x)=\color{red}{0}$$
are represented by the intersection of the graph with the $Ox$ axis whose equation is $y=\color{red}{0}$.
you see that $ p$ and $ q$ are roots.

The roots of the equation$$y=f(x)=\color{red}{k} \; with \; k>0$$

will be represented by the intersection of the curve and the horizontal line whose equation is $ y=\color{red}{k}$.

we see that kind of line intersects the curve at a single point. So, the equation $y=k (>0)$ has only one root.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $ t= \frac1{x-p}$ into $ (x-p)^2(x-q)=k$ to obtain the depressed cubic equation

$$t^3+ \frac{q-p}k t-\frac1k=0$$

whose discriminant is $ \Delta = - \frac{4(q-p)^3}{k^3} - \frac{27}{k^2 }<0$. Thus, the equation has one real root.